How I place a global variable at a compile-time known address?
I'm writing code for a specific stm32 chip with memory mapped peripherals. I happen to know that one of the GPIO ports, GPIOA, is controlled by several 32 bit ints located starting at address 0x40018000. How can I express this information at compile time?
My initial attempt looked like this:
struct Gpio {
    volatile uint32_t crl;
    volatile uint32_t crh;
    // ...
};

constinit Gpio& GPIOA = *reinterpret_cast<Gpio*>(0x40018000);

This seems like a sensible way to say "The reference GPIOA refers to an object located at memory address 0x40018000
Unfortunately this does not work:
error: 'constinit' variable 'GPIOA' does not have a constant initializer
error: 'reinterpret_cast' from integer to pointer

What options are available to me? How can I spell a specific numeric memory address at compile time?
Prior research:

Is it possible to have a pointer literal?

It is not possible to have a pointer literal.


How to place a variable at a given absolute address in memory (with GCC)

Globals can be placed at specific addresses using linker scripts.
This happens at link time, not compile time.




I'd consider this outside the boundaries of standard, portable code. It is inherently specific and not portable. 1) Why is link time, rather than compile time an issue? Link time is a normal time for address assignment for bare metal embedded code. 2) I've normally done this in C, not C++. Generally it has been tool chain specific methods. I have seen this done using: compiler specific attributes in source code; pointer casts in source code; linker configurations; assembly code modules.

@AviBerger BSPs are C libraries and impose too much overhead at runtime. The OP needs to run slimmer and faster than C.

Does it have to be constinit? Perhaps Gpio& GPIOA = *new(reinterpret_cast<Gpio*>(0x40018000)) Gpio; would be good enough?

The embedded industry needs to consider C++ metaprogramming for optimized and safe libraries. Best solutions are not the simplest ones. I would consider monostate class better design than global reference. Moreover, you need to think about initialization and how to avoid unwanted multiple initialization of control registers. The solution involves more complex designs. Otherwise, there will be unnecessary memory overhead.

@Red.Wave You're right, Bad terminology on my part. I was thinking of something much more limited and basic. Basically a setup for mapping struct variables to memory mapped peripherals and not much else, like the OP is trying to do. I've used such things. Now that I think about it, I don't really seem to have a proper name to use for it.

The vendor supplies a part specific stm32xxxxx.h header that defines MCU registers.  It even defined a symbol GPIOA so if you needlessly choose to create your own, you'd do well to use a namespace or at least a unique prefix.

@Clifford Of course my real code is in a namespace. It was not relevant to the question of how to place variables at specific addresses.

@Filipp well the vendor's header does pretty much what you have done with a C cast and with C linkage for language interoperability.

It turns out there is a straightforward way to place a global variable at a specific address.
It is possible to directly set the address of a symbol using linker scripts.
In C++, simply declare the variable like so:
extern Gpio GPIO;

Do not define this variable in any .cpp file.
Then, in the linker script, give it an address:
GPIO = 0x40018000;

When linking, tell the linker to use your script using the -T option.
Your program should now link without any undefined reference errors. The symbol will refer to the memory location you specified. One limitation is there will not be any initialization for this value, but this is desirable for a memory mapped register.

I don't know how to do it on C++, but I know how to do it on C.
I think there will be something same.
For C,

you can use a compiler attribute keyword to place a variable in specified address. eg:
int var __attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x20000000"))) = 0x1234;

but it relays on the link script and ARM compiler.

you can use linker script to do it.
specify a section name in code.
int var __attribute__((section(".mysection"))) = 0x1234;



and then in your link scripts, to place this section at an addresss you wanted.

Both aren't a general C thing. This is specifically a GCC extension (and a Clang one by compatibility).

Currently the language doesn't permit getting a pointer/reference to such an object as a variable at compile-time. The only way to form the pointer is using reinterpret_cast and this disqualifies the initialization from being a constant expression.
However, it doesn't seem that you actually need the initialization at compile-time. If you are fine with risking dynamic initialization, then constinit can be dropped and the compiler won't complain anymore. This is only a problem if you intent to use the pointer/reference during the initialization of another non-local variable. In that case you potentially risk running into the static initialization order fiasco.
The behavior of pointers cast from integer values is completely implementation-defined (except for round-trip casts). However, nothing in your shown code is actually creating an object at the address represented by the pointer. Although behavior is implementation-defined, it seems reasonable that you probably should use a placement-new to properly create an object at the address before and obtain a pointer to that object.
So e.g.:
Gpio& GPIOA = *std::construct_at(reinterpret_cast<Gpio*>(0x40018000));


As pointed out by @TedLyngmo, using std::construct_at will cause the object to be value-initialized, which by the looks of how you defined the class, probably will cause all of your members to be zero-initialized. If you do not intent this access to happen, then you need to use default-intialization, for which you need an explicit placement-new:
Gpio& GPIOA = *::new(reinterpret_cast<void*>(0x40018000)) GPIOA;

Formally, this doesn't access the member subobjects, but still results in them having an indeterminate state. So it isn't useful if the assumption is to preserve some initial state of that memory. The standard doesn't have any notion for that. In the standard there must always be an object in memory that actually holds the value.

Maybe worth a note that using construct_at rather than a raw placement-new will write 0 to the volatile uint32_ts in Gpio. It could make the hardware do things.... :-)

Indeed, those registers have a well-defined initial state. Perhaps start_lifetime_as would be more appropriate.

@Filipp Yes, that would work too but I haven't seen any library supporting it yet so a raw placement new is probably the best option to date.

@TedLyngmo Yes, I didn't think about that. Added a note.

@Filipp Yes, if you use a placement-new, then formally the value of the object will be indeterminate. It won't have any value derived from the bit state prior to the placement-new. I am not sure whether start_lifetime_at would then be guaranteed to behave in the intended way. But in either case, all of this is implementation-defined to begin with. It isn't really possible to make a good decision without a specification from the compiler vendor. But in practice that doesn't exist and nobody considers that objects have to be created properly.
